# How to add multiple data of matrices using python in separate files

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to add two data which are 23x23 matrices using python, but I am not sure how to get desired output.

The data have totally 23 lines although I showed here only one row.

Any help would be greatful.

Code:

```
    import numpy as np

    data2 = np.loadtxt('20.dat', dtype='float')
    data3 = np.loadtxt('21.dat', dtype='float')
    print(data2+data3)
```

What I've been getting:

```
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  21. 196.
   95.  35.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
```

Desired output:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 21 196 95 35 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: How about using an integer type?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what the problem is.

Comment: The most important one it should be in a separate line to plot the data. Currently it takes two lines. I guess the problem is there are many spaces between columns. Integer doesn't work..

Comment: `sum_data = data2 + data3` and then `print (' '.join(sum_data.astype('str')))`. Or `print (' '.join(sum_data.astype('int').astype('str')))` would look more like your example output.

Comment: Do you think that maybe it's in two lines because the string just wraps?  Or are you suggesting that there's a newline in the middle after 196?  Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the result is technically correct (i.e. the numbers are correct), but your issue is with the formatting.

You can format a single line the way you wanted it by first converting each element to an `int`, then converting it to a `str`, and then joining on it (separating each element with a single space).

```py
In [32]: b
Out[32]:
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,  21., 196.,  95.,  35.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.])

In [33]: " ".join(str(int(elt)) for elt in b)
Out[33]: '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 21 196 95 35 0 0 0 0 0 0 0'
```

Even better, use `astype`

```
" ".join(b.astype('int').astype(str'))
```

Thanks to a comment by @Xirtaminu